# Make An Inline-Block List Span 2 Lines Without A <BR> or Wrapping Part Of It In A Div

Tags: html, css

I have a menu that's generated by a plugin, and I need it to span 2 lines instead of 1 like so:

**Example:**

[image: Example]

**I Cannot:**

- I can't wrap certain `li` in a div/span
- I can't add a `<br>` where I need the break

**I Tried:**

- I tried adding a Pseudo Element to "Happy" with `display: block` to create a line break, but couldn't get it to work the way I intended

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/3xy405oj/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `content: "\A"; white-space: pre;` on the `after` pseudo-element might help you

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xy405oj/5/)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a width to the ul :

```
ul {
  width: 40%;
}
```

To make it pretty, remove text-align center from the li and add it to ul instead.

Then add margin 0 auto to ul to make it pretty :)

```
ul {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kq03kzwt/

Comment: +1 as this will work. My issue with this though, it wouldn't be consistent across varying desktop screen resolutions

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

**CSS**

```
    ul {
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 2%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li>Crazy</li>
  <li>Awesome</li>
  <li>Smile</li>
  <li class="break-after">Happy</li>
  <li>Jitter</li>
  <li>Cool</li>
  <li>Mango</li>
</ul>
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/luispa/3xy405oj/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can just float all the elements inside the ul and use clear: left.

```
<ul>
  <li>Crazy</li>
  <li>Awesome</li>
  <li>Smile</li>
  <li>Happy</li>
  <li class="break">Jitter</li>
  <li>Cool</li>
  <li>Mango</li>
</ul>

ul {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 overflow: auto;
}

li {
 margin: 0 5px;
 float: left;
}

.break {
 clear: left;
}
```